# How to redistribute DLLs with a C# application?

Tags: c#, dll, software-distribution, redistributable

A beginner question I am sure, but I have just started working with a DLL provided by Vandyke software (VRALib, a COM and .NET API for scripting SSH2 connections) so while I am  happily now coding on my PC, I am not sure how you go about redistributing DLLs along with the application to other PCs.

Does any one have some beginners guides to working with 3rd party DLLs and best practice methods and tips / tricks for redistribution?

Comment: it would be helpful to know, if the 3rd party dlls are managed or unmanaged.

Comment: Is this a .NET DLL, or a COM DLL or an old fashioned windows DLL?

Comment: @Maciek, @iandotkelly: To be fair the OP actually did mention _something_ along those lines, but some plonker edited it out.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, @iandotkelly: I removed the name of the company and the library from what seemed like a post that was low on content and high on advertising. The name and producer of the DLL are completely irrelevant to this question, so I've removed them again.

Comment: Most people use an installer... What's the question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, well if its a COM DLL with a managed .NET API, you need to make sure that you have a means for installing and registering the COM DLL on the PC.  The .NET API can just be copied along with your application.

There are various ways of registering DLLs, there's a command line program regsvr32 which is a bit ugly but functional.  Here is an [article](http://www.zorched.net/2009/01/01/register-and-unregister-com-dll-from-net-code/) describing how to register COM DLLs from .NET code.

Does the Vandyke software come with an installer that you can just run from your installer?  Do they provide a means of running the installer in a silent mode?

Comment: Thank you for that responce, pointed me in the right direction for some reserch and think I know get the idea. I can see this progaming lark is going to get fun :) Answer one question another 5 come along! at least it keeps the grey cells ticking.

Comment: COM DLLs can be a bit of a nightmare - especially if shared between lots of different applications.  If your application is the only one likely to use this DLL and no other applications on the PC are likely to update at some point then it does get easier.  Good luck.

Comment: unlikely to be shared, Really I am just looking for a good way to implement SSH in my c# project. I am sure there are other ways to achieve the same but I am in now way a cc# expert and able to implement SSH from scratch. But eventuly I want a complete stand alone application, this DLL was jsut the first I came across that could do the trick, but this is the first time I have played with DLL's so going in blind.

Comment: Here is an article about using OpenSSL with C# -http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sslclasses.aspx